# Filter Facebook Friends by list types

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook graph API, I can easily retrieve my friends list. But is it possible to filter them by (because there are hundreds of friends) by various list types (highschool, work, college, etc)?

Is this possible with graph API?

Comment: I wonder if you have found a solution for this?